# Python - reuse user input on menu

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-3.x, menu

What's the best way to implement this -  reuse user input on menu?
Here's my sample code below:

```
def input():
    user = raw_input('user: ')
    passwd = getpass.getpass('passwd: ')
    return (user,passwd)

def function1():
    user, passwd, vcenter = input() 
do something

def function2():
    user, passwd, vcenter = input() 
do something

def function3():
    user, passwd, vcenter = input()     
    do something

def main():
    while True:
        if choice == 1:
            function1()
        elif choice == 2:
            function2()
        elif choice == 3:
            function3()
        else:
            print 'Choose from the options only!'
        break
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but I have a feeling that your question is too broad. This website usually focuses on questions more specific than "what's the best way to implement xyz?"

Comment: As @DaoWen said, Please narrow down your question, preferrably providing pseudocode of what the end result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think i get what you mean, you want to use the input() once in the while loop, and not repeat calling it in every function. if so I suggest this solution:

```
def input():
    user = raw_input('user: ')
    passwd = getpass.getpass('passwd: ')
    return (user,passwd)

def function1(param):
    user, passwd = param
    do something

def function2(param):
    user, passwd = param
    do something

def function3(param):
    user, passwd = param
    do something

def main():
    while True:
        if choice in [1,2,3]:
            param = input() 
        if choice == 1:
            function1(param)
        elif choice == 2:
            function2(param)
        elif choice == 3:
            function3(param)
        else:
            print 'Choose from the options only (1, 2, 3): '
        break
```

hope this helps.